# Node Server Geolocation

Tags: node.js, geolocation

Is there a way for a Node server to work out it's accurate (i.e. GPS) location without using the HTML Geolocation API from the browser?  It also needs to be disconnected from the internet, i.e not depend on some external lookup.

In my case I have a server which is a laptop, not connected to the internet, and physically moving around a location.  When the client connects to the server, the server needs to already know where it is, the client may not be in the same location.  Imagine the client starting up a map and drawing two dots, one with the location of the server and the other with the location of the client.

Basically, does an equivalent to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` exist for a server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is to have some GPS or GNSS hardware attached.  After that, it's very easy.

Almost all of those GPS/GNSS units show up as a serial port.  You can open the serial port using whatever package is appropriate for whatever system you're using.  From there, a handful of protocols are used but NMEA is the most common and easiest to deal with.  NMEA data looks like this:

```
$GNRMC,143909.00,A,5107.0020216,N,11402.3294835,W,0.036,348.3,210307,0.0,E,A*31
```

In this example, the latitude is 51 degrees, 7.0017737 minutes North, 114 degrees, 02.3291611 minutes West.  There are [NPM packages available for parsing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nmea-0183).

Comment: Also, you can find acceptable USB GNSS units on Alibaba and what not for ~$15.

Comment: Thanks, I assumed a hardware solution would be the answer.  It seems odd that a browser can access location but there is no way for the server to access the same functionality.
There is a Windows location API which could be used from a C++ Node plugin, but the server will probably be running on Linux.

Comment: @TheZapper The Geolocation API is provided by the browser, and not V8.  You could certainly copy that API and make a native Node.js module for it.  Perhaps someone has already done that effort, but I don't know of any.  Either way though, if you want accuracy, I assume you're going to want more data than is provided via the location API.  The Geolocation API can use many data sources (including guesses based on nearby WiFi and cellular base stations).  If you use NMEA directly, you get the real GNSS data, as well as information about accuracy.

Answer (score -1):

There is something called IP-based Geo-location.It basically is a mapping of an IP address to a geographic location of an Internet-connected machine. Check this [Medium Article to find some IP Geo location APIs](http://IP-based%20Geolocation%20is%20a%20mapping%20of%20an%20IP%20address%20to%20a%20geographic%20location%20of%20an%20Internet-connected%20computing%20or%20mobile%20device)

Comment: Since I don't wanna hijack this by posting an answer just suggesting a library, I'll put this here. There's a library for it: https://www.npmjs.com/package/geoip-lite

Comment: This is not useful when not connected to the internet, as there would be no public IP address to utilize.

Comment: I did specifically mention that the machine is not connected to the internet, so this won't work.  Also, generally an IP lookup is not very accurate, this needs to be GPS accuracy.